# Getting "Attempt to get length of null array" error

Tags: android, rest

I m getting "Attempt to get length of null array" error.
I m trying to fetch the random quotes as following from the link https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random when I try to click the button :
type    "success"
value
id  7
quote   "The real benefit of Boot, however, is that it's just Spring. That means any direction the code takes, regardless of complexity, I know it's a safe bet."

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnCallRestApi;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnCallRestApi = findViewById(R.id.btnCallRestApi);
        btnCallRestApi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //call Rest Api
                new HttpReqTask().execute();

            }
        });
    }
    private class HttpReqTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Value[]> {
        @Override
        protected Value[] doInBackground(Void... params){
            try{
                String apiUrl = "https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random";
                RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
                rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
                Value[] quotes = rest.getForObject(apiUrl, Value[].class);
                return quotes;
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Log.e("Could not get Quotes",ex.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Value[] quotes){
            super.onPostExecute(quotes);
            for(Value v:quotes){
                Log.i("id: ", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
                Log.i("quote: ", v.getQuote());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quote.java

```
 public Quote() {
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
```

Value.java

```
 public Value() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getQuote() {
        return this.quote;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setQuote(String quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", quote='" + quote + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

Comment: Btw, `Log.e` accepts a `Throwable` which can be passed as the third argument, while the first argument is meant to be a tag for easier searching in the logcat. (It should be `Log.e("MainActivity", "Message here", /* exception here */)`) - same goes for the other `Log.*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to do a loop on a null array , which trigger a `NPE` , try to handle it with a `try/catch` clause

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Value[] quotes){
            super.onPostExecute(quotes);   
    try {
        for(Value v:quotes){
            Log.i("id: ", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
            Log.i("quote: ", v.getQuote());
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.print("Caught the NullPointerException");
    }
```

**edit** for the new issue :

i think you are reading the JSON OBJECT wrongly !

Comment: This seems to work but now I m getting this error when I m trying to click the button to fetch the random qutoes:
E/Could not get Quotes: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of org.hello.rest.Value[] out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: check my edit , and please consider my answer for your first question and if you still have issue with your json please ask a new question